# Openpyxl include a totalsrow that subtotals visible rows in Table

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to create a Table.  But I cannot figure out how to get the TotalsRow to appear and I cannot find any guidance through searching.  Only the [openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/table.html#TableColumn), which I cannot make sense of it.  Here is the code I have:

```
LastRow = ws.max_row
tab = Table(displayName="Table10", ref="A1:CU198",
            totalsRowShown=True)

style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium9", showFirstColumn=False,
                       showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=False, showColumnStripes=True)
tblcolmn = TableColumn(id=1,name='TableTotals',totalsRowFunction='sum', totalsRowLabel='Totals')
tab.TableColumn = tblcolmn
tab.tableStyleInfo = style
ws.add_table(tab)
```

But it does not show the TotalsRow, so I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Oh, and I cannot calculate the sums in python, becuase I need the sum formula to change when I filter the Table.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the solution with Openpyxl, but I did find the solution with xlsxwriter using the below code.  Hope this helps someone:

```
ColDict = [{'header': DFColumnHeadersList,'total_string':'Totals','total_function':'sum' } for ColList in df.columns]
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(PathFileName)
ws = wb.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
ws.add_table(0,0,198,99,{'data': TestFileList, 'total_row': True, 'columns': ColDict,'last_column': False, 'banded_columns': True, 'name':'Table10'})
wb.close()
```